# Where to call unregisterReceiver in an activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I recently have been implementing an application where I register a receiver within a subclass and later unregister as the last thing I do inside of the class before I move onto another activity.

However, when I come back to the activity and initialize the subclass again I get the error below even though I know that unregisterReceiver() is called.

```
Activity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mycomp.devel.ControlActivity$BLERunnable$1@6bb9d96 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Does unregister *have* to be within onPause() or onDestroy() in order to work effectively or could there be something else getting in the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want it to work. If you want the receiver to triggered only when the activity is in the foreground, use `onResume()/onPause()`.

If you want it to additionally trigger when you activity is paused, use `onCreate()/onDestroy()`.

Think of a use case. Say your receiver is called when some user's data is updated and hence you need to reload it. If you did `onResume()/onPause()`, you need to reload the user data in `onResume()` because you won't have bee notified if it changed while your app was paused. OTOH, if you register in `onCreate()`, you only need to load the user data in `onCreate()`.

The downside of `onCreate()/onPause()` might be that your app is updating it's UI when it's paused, potentially for no reason because the user is never going to come back to the app.

This is just trying to get you to think about what is going to be best for you since I don't know your exact use case.

Comment: So it sounds like it is not common practice to register/unregister a receiver within a runnable thread class inside of the activity?

Comment: You need to write your code so a register is coupled with unregister and lifecycle methods are a convenient way to do that. It's also good practice to do things like this on the main thread so you don't need to worry about synchronization (lifecycle methods are of course always called on the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

Usually `onResume()` and `onPause()` are recommended to register and unregister the receiver.

But if you are registering `BroadcastReceiver` inside `onCreate()` you have to unregister it in `onDestroy()`. And It it necessary to unregister the broadcast receiver in android .

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Other than that `onDestroy(` will not get called in some cases so it might lead to leak . So preferred way is register in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()` or `onStart()/onStop()` .  If this fits the requirement you can use `onResume()/onPause()` or `onStart()/onStop()`.

Or if registerReceiver is inside `onCreate()` then unregister the receiver inside `onDestroy()`.

Comment: The only time `onDestroy()` is not called is when the process is dying. In that case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeah .. Thx . . This means process is died so no memory leaks . Right ?

Comment: I am working with the BluetoothLeService and have been following the googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt example. But need to do different things within the DeviceControlActivity and thought it would be easier to wrap most of its functionality within it's own class eventually running into errors with this receiver.